# didReceiveScriptMessage NOT working in iOS8 WKWebView

Tags: ios8

I have such a Js injected in webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler:

```
function postMyMessage()
{
    try {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.SimpleBrowser.postMessage('JS for qq.com called');
    } catch(err) {
        alert('The native context does not exist yet ' + err);
    }
}

postMyMessage()
```

implementing the delegate like this

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message
{
    NSLog(@"Message: %@", message.body);
}
```

The problem is this log only show once, never come out after, even through load another WKWebView.

I got this err msg when NOT receiving the message log.

alert The native context does not exist yet TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'window.webkit.messageHandlers')

Is is a bug? any solution now?

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. I'll let you know if my debugging goes anywhere.

Comment: thanks, I look in the WebKit commit log, maybe beta5 will fix this

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-changes@lists.webkit.org/msg73383.html

Comment: iOS8 beta5 already fix this problem

Comment: I'm also experiencing this too, My current xcode version:6.1.1 and ipad version: 8.1. How to know the beta version
With my current version how to resolve this?

Comment: let us know, how to import webkit framework which is updated in beta5 version